# What is wrong with my maze-solving algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search, maze

I have used a DFS-algorithm for noting the moves needed to solve the maze. There's a `startVertex` and an `endVertex`. My code is as follows:

```
private void DFS(int vertex, boolean visited[], LinkedList<Move> output) {

    visited[vertex] = true;

    for (int neighbor: g.neighbors(vertex)) {
        if (visited[neighbor] != true) {
            if (neighbor == vertex + 1)
                output.add(Move.RIGHT);
            else if (neighbor == vertex - 1)
                output.add(Move.LEFT);
            else if (neighbor == vertex + Math.sqrt(g.size()))
                output.add(Move.DOWN);
            else
                output.add(Move.UP);
            if (neighbor == endVertex)
                break;
            DFS(neighbor, visited, output);
        }
        else {
            output.removeLast();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the `removeLast()` function when all the surrounding neighbors have been explored and thus that particular vertex remains of no use. But I think that the error lies there only.

The size of graph `g` is `n*n` because the original maze is a 2D square matrix with n rows and n columns.

Comment: `g.neighbors(vertex)`  - `g` is not defined in the code, so it needs guess work.  For more efficient and effective help post [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

- You need to clear visited when leaving DFS (and the endVertex hasn't been found)
- output.removeLast should be symmetrical to output.add
- break only leaves the innermost loop. Is that what you want?
- You probably want to let DFS return whether the endVertex was found, so you know the search can be stopped in higher layers